# Ubuntu 20.04 restarting on its own - how to identify the source of the issue?

Tags: kernel, hardware, restart, syslog

I have Ubuntu 20.04 and have been having this restarting issue from a couple of days.
I did not do anything special at software level, at some point the computer just started to restart by itself, not always at the same time, once after hours, another time after minutes and then always more often.

The attempts I made to identify the issue until now were to remove the UPS and disconnect all my old 3 HHDs, just keeping 2 SSDs. From this morning it seems to work and it's not restarting, so my question are:

- is that possible that old/damanged HHDs were causing the restarting issue? Could it be possible that it's because of broken HHD cables? How can I be sure / test that it's a cable-related issue, in case?
- is there anything I can do on Ubuntu to identify the reason of the issue? I tried to read `dmesg` output but I could not see specific issues. I also ran `last reboot` but I am not sure about the utility of that! What else can I do?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

The information you provide lead to one suspect. A partially faulty Power Supply Unit that cannot support the total power consumption the devices require. By removing the disks you reduced that consumption.

Another possible reason could be some kind of cable shortcut or bad power cable connection on any of the disks you removed but I think this is less likely.

These malfunctions though cannot be logged because they're very sudden and the system does not actually detect them since it restarts abruptly.

Comment: thanks, how should I proceed in your opinion? I dont have another power supply to try as a replacement, so I was thinking to reconnect one HDD per time and check the stability again. If it happens again I'm gonna try to change the cable for that HDD and if it still happens it's probable that it's the power supply's fault.

Comment: @Frank. Yes, since you don't have another PSU, this is the best you can do.